# Set function equal to a matrix

Tags: matrix

I'm trying to make a function that is equal to a matrix which has variables in it. For example, I'm trying to do this:

```
F = {x1 + x2, x1 - x2};
F[x1_, x2_] = F
```

So I want a matrix function with variables $x1$ and $x2$. Is there a way to do this? Or, I might want a function where the matrix is

```
F = {{x1 + x2, x1}, {x1 - x2, x2 - x1}}
```

Comment: Just do it: `Function[{x1,x2},{{x1+x2,x1},{x1-x2,x2-x1}}]`
See the documentation for `Function`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code

```
F = {x1 + x2, x1 - x2};
F[x1_, x2_] = F
```

throws the error

```
Set::write: Tag List in {x1+x2,x1-x2}[x1_,x2_] is Protected.
```

As you can see in this message, the head `F` of the expression `F[x1_, x2_]` got evaluated to `{x1 + x2, x1 - x2}`, which yielded `{x1 + x2, x1 - x2}[x1_, x2_]`.

`Set` tried to assign an expression to this result, with an attempt to store the definition on the symbol `List`, which is the outer-most head

```
Head[Head[{x1 + x2, x1 - x2}[x1_, x2_]]]
(* List *)
```

This failed because the symbol `List` is protected:

```
Attributes[List]
(* {Locked, Protected} *)
```

You can solve this issue by choosing different names for the matrix and the associated function:

```
f = {x1 + x2, x1 - x2};
fmat[x1_, x2_] = f;

fmat[1, 1]
(* {2, 0} *)

g = {{x1 + x2, x1}, {x1 - x2, x2 - x1}};
gmat[x1_, x2_] = g;

gmat[1, 1]
(* {{2, 1}, {0, 0}} *)
```

Comment: That makes sense. Is there a way to have a variable that will be the argument of the matrix function? Like if I want x = [1,1]; gmat[x]

Comment: You can use `x = {1, 1}`, and then `gmat@@x`. Otherwise you could define `gmat2[{x1_, x2_}] = g` (note the additional braces in the l.h.s.), and do `gmat2[x]`.